# Extract substring with sed/awk/grep from .gff file

Tags: linux, shell, sed, grep

I have a file containing multiple lines like this:

```
NODE_1_length   Prodigal:2.6    CDS     11      274     .       +       0       ID=PROKKA_00001;inference=ab initio prediction:Prodigal:2.6;locus_tag=PROKKA_00001;product=hypothetical protein
```

And I want to extract the ID=PROKKA_[whatever number] and everything that comes after 'product=' to obtain an output like this:

```
ID=PROKKA_00001 product=hypothetical protein
```

I am not very skilled in using sed, so I tried to adapt some solutions I found here and around but didn't manage to get through.  It is also fine if the solution comes in two step (one for the ID, one for the product), then I can merge the two results in a single file.

I would be grateful if you could include an explanation of the regex used.

So far I tried to split the problem in two (starting from the ID) and tried:

```
grep -o 'ID=PROKKA_[0-9]{1,5}*'
sed 's/^ID=PROKKA[0-9]*;//g/
grep -Po 'ID="K[^"]*'
```

but of course none of them worked.
Thanks for helping!

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code. StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not intended as a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it.
Given the tags you've included, I'd expect to see shell and sed code in your question. I've voted to close this question, since without your work so far, it's off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @ghoti gotcha, updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `grep -oE`:

```
grep -oE 'ID=PROKKA_[0-9]+|product=[^;:]+' file
```

```
ID=PROKKA_00001
product=hypothetical protein
```

If you want result in same line then use `grep + paste`:

```
grep -oE 'ID=PROKKA_[0-9]+|product=[^;:]+' file | paste -s
```

Comment: That's perfect!!! I added a |paste - - in order to have one result (ID + product) per line. Thanks a lot.